# Can it's possible to make multiple server in a same domain sub-directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns

It's just my project. It's growing up and I want to add a new server as a sub-directory on the same domain. Is it possible to make sub-directory like:

example.com 127.0.0.1

example.com/project1/ 127.0.0.2

example.com/project2/ 127.0.0.3

How I config a DNS or Apache to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to implement a proxy which can be done with [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html). I assume the sites are already running on `127.0.0.2` and `127.0.0.3` and the public frontend is on `127.0.0.1`

You will need to edit the configuration files on `127.0.0.1` and either in the main configuration (for a single site) or virtual host block for a virtual host, add the [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) configuration:

```
ProxyPass       /project1/  http://127.0.0.2/
ProxyPass       /project2/  http://127.0.0.3/
```

This will send all requests from `/project1/` to `http://127.0.0.2/`, if you want to keep this server hidden, or it's not accessible by the public such as an internal network address you will need to set up a reverse proxy so the results are fed back to users via your public front end, so you will need to add [ProxyPassReverse](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) configuration:

```
ProxyPassReverse /project1/  http://127.0.0.2/
ProxyPassReverse /project2/  http://127.0.0.3/
```

Further to this, you will need to enable the proxy modules in your configuration files as well, these are what I have enabled for a basic reverse proxy

```
LoadModule  proxy_module         modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule  proxy_http_module    modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

There are some other modules that could be important depending on your situation

```
mod_proxy_connect    This handles the CONNECT function if connecting to https:// servers
mod_proxy_ftp        This handles connections to FTP servers
mod_proxy_ajp        This handles connections to tomcat/AJP servers
mod_headers          This can modify response and request headers
mod_deflate          This negotiates compression with backends
mod_proxy_html       This is a 3rd party module which will rewrite HTML links to the proxy address space
```

Comment: +1 Good explanation, although seems to me the OP is talking about sub-domains. But, who knows anyway.